# Svelte: How to bind to a defined object inside an array

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

Here's the code:

```
<script>
let array = [
    {id: 1, first: "x"},
    {id: 2, second: "y"}
];
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={array.first}/>
```

Now if you change the value inside the input and look at the value of `array.first`, it will be correct.

However, if you look at the whole array object (i.e. `console.log(array)`) it will not be updated and instead will show you the original values it was initiated with.

Further to this, when putting a nested object in:

```
let array = [
    {id: 1, first: [{id: 1, value: "x"}]},
    {id: 2, second: [{id: 1, value: "y"}]}
];
```

Results in an undefined error from Svelte when binding to `array.first.value`. However, when not binding to it and only interacting with it through JS, the value is accessible and defined.

What am I not doing right here? Or is it not possible to bind to nested objects in arrays? Or even non-nested.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you bind to the `first` property of the element at index `0` in the array, not the `first` property of the array itself.

This will also work for the nested example `array[0].first[0].value` in your question.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/034dd73915804e2fb37dbd8549b937dd?version=3.55.0))**

```html
<script>
    let array = [
        { id: 1, first: "x" },
        { id: 2, second: "y" }
    ];
    
    $: console.log(array);
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={array[0].first}/>
```